# Press a button to execute an operation instead of using back button

Tags: android, android-activity

I am selecting an image from gallery.

[image: press back button]

When I press the back button, the `getResultCamera.launch(intent)` is called and an operation takes place.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selected_image)

        image = findViewById(R.id.the_selected_image);
        srButton = findViewById(R.id.super_resolution_button)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_CODE)
            } else {
                chooseImageGallery()
            }
        } else {
            chooseImageGallery()
        }


    }


private fun chooseImageGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        getResultCamera.launch(intent)
    }


 private val getResultCamera =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) {
            if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                imageUri = it.data?.data as Uri
                image.setImageURI(imageUri)
                intent.putExtra("imageuri", imageUri)
                

            }
        }
```

So, it goes to the `MainActivity`, it loads the image and the operation takes place there.

Now, I want to use a button for the user to press instead of the back button.

So, I am trying something like:

```
private val getResultCamera =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) {
            if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                imageUri = it.data?.data as Uri
                image.setImageURI(imageUri)
                
                srButton.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
                    intent.putExtra("imageuri", imageUri)
                    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }

            }
        }
```

[image: with button]

but when I press the button, it just returns to the `MainActivity` without executing the operation.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want to achieve, do you want the back button to do something other than go to the last activity? Or do you want your start button to have the same function that the back button would usually have? Or something else?

Comment: @HapaxLegomenon:Yes, I want the start button to have the same behaviour as when pressing the back button. When pressing the back button returns in the MainActivity where I call the `registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())` and load the image uri and execute some operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `finish()` in the button's OnClickListener. This basically acts as though the user pressed the back button.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way may help you

```
private val pickImages = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()){ uri: Uri? ->
     uri?.let { it ->
         // The image was saved into the given Uri -> do something with it
             imageUri = it

          }
     }        
        
        
    pickImages.launch("image/*")
        

    srButton.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
         intent.putExtra("imageuri", imageUri)
         val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
         startActivity(intent)
    }


 @Override
 protected void onBackPressed(){
  //Do not call super.onbackpressed here
 }
```